# How to use select statement to insert values on a table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert theses values to my table student but I have an error

```
insert into student(first_name,last_name,student_number,professor_id)
  values(Eden,Yuan,323744573, 
  select professor_id from PROFESSORS where professor_name =  'Chu ')
```

I get an error

> saying missing expression

Answer (score 2):

you can use this way  (assuming that  professor_id is the column you need)

```
insert into student(first_name,last_name,student_number,professor_id) 
select 'Eden', 'Eden', 323744573, column_professor_id 
from PROFESSORS where professor_name = 'Chu ' ;
```

(In your query is missing the column in the select )